# How should I create H2 using SpringBoot?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, h2

I'm starting to play with Spring Boot and as part of that I want to create an in memory DB to work with and bootstrap with the application.

Given the config/code below I get no errors in the startup log and can access the application ok, so it does startup (I get template errors about objects not existing), but I don't get any data back from the DAO when calling findAll() (or if I try to call findById(int) ).

So while it seems things are ok (no error in log, log shows it finds the sql to create schema ad attempts to run the data.sql statements) when I try to access data via the DAO I get no Exception, but no data returned.

Any ideas or observations on the code that might be a problem?

I've added the Spring Data / H2 stuff to my pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Spring DAO:

```
public interface PersonDao extends CrudRepository<Person, Integer> {
}
```

DB props in application.properties:

```
server.contextPath=/
server.port=8080
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.ftl

datasource.mine.jdbcUrl=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/mem:clubmanagement
datasource.mine.user=sa
datasource.mine.password=
datasource.mine.poolSize=30

logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=DEBUG

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

My service:

```
@Service
public class MemberServiceImpl implements MemberService {

@Autowired
PersonDao dao;

@Override
public Optional<ClubMember> getClubMember(int id) {
    Person dbPerson = dao.findOne(id);
    if(dbPerson == null) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
    return Optional.of(fromEntity(dbPerson));
}

@Override
public List<ClubMember> allMembers() {
    Iterable<Person> people = dao.findAll();
    List<ClubMember> members = new ArrayList<>();
    people.forEach(person -> {
        members.add(fromEntity(person));
    });
    return members;
}

private ClubMember fromEntity(Person p) {
    ClubMember member = new ClubMember();
    member.setCurrentGrade(p.getCurrentGrade());
    member.setFirstName(p.getFirstName());
    member.setLastName(p.getLastName());
    member.setAssociationMemberId(p.getAssociationMemberId());
    member.setLastGradingDate(p.getLastGradingDate());
    return member;
}
}
```

Schema.sql in resources/ :

```
create table CLUB
  (id int not null, name varchar(60), association_member_id int);

create table PERSON
(
id int not null, grade_id int, first_name varchar(35), last_name varchar(35),
association_membership varchar(12), last_grading_date date
);

create table GRADE
  (id int not null, name varchar(20));
```

In data.sql (again in resources directory):

```
insert into club (id, name, association_member_id) values (1, 'some club', '123');

insert into person (id, grade_id, first_name, last_name, association_membership, last_grading_date)
values (1, 1, 'name', 'lastname', 'a1234', '2016-03-23');
```

Entity class I am trying to retrieve (Trying to use Lombock, also new to me, to generate getters/setters):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public @Data class Person {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@JoinColumn(name = "grade_id")
private GRADE currentGrade;

@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "association_membership")
private String associationMemberId;

@Column(name = "last_grading_date")
@Temporal(value = TemporalType.DATE)
private Date lastGradingDate;
}
```

Comment: Did you set `spring.datasource.initialize` in your `application.properties` ?

Comment: turn on the sql logging to see if there are logs: add `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` in application.properties. And maybe look if you have all necessary annotations set. Maybe `@Transactional` is missing anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending some time working through some ideas with @Safwan Hijazi in chat, came to the conclusion that what is happening is that the schema.sql and data.sql were being run but then the schema was recreated depending on the value (or lack of) of the spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto property.

If not specified, spring/hibernate between them ended up recreating an empty schema (default seems to be create-drop for in memory DB).

If set the 'none' then that wouldn't happen and DB as created by the schema and data sql scripts would remain and the application functioned correctly.

See also: [CrudRepository not reading data from schema.sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921489/crudrepository-not-reading-data-from-schema-sql)

Answer (score 8):

you want to add H2 database, but you added HSQLDB, please replace

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

with

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

EDIT

I noticed you have multiple issues in your code:

1. default schema file name is schema.sql not Schema.sql
2. names of tables in schema.sql are different than names in data.sql (PERSON vs person)
3. you used this `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` in application.properties (default option), in this case JPA databases schema only will be automatically created (**without data creation**), so data.sql will not be executed, to fix this issues you can use `validate` or `update` option

I will write one simple example how to use H2 database with spring boot and JPA

This is the project structure:

[image]

Grade Entity

```
package com.shijazi;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="GRADE")
public class Grade {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Grade(int id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Grade() {
    }



}
```

GradeRepository.java

```
package com.shijazi;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface GradeRepository extends JpaRepository<Grade, Integer> {

}
```

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private GradeRepository gradeRepo;

    @RequestMapping(value="api/test")
    public List<Grade> getall()
    {
        return  gradeRepo.findAll();
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

schema.sql

```
create table GRADE (id int not null, name varchar(20));
```

data.sql

```
insert into GRADE (id, name) values (2,  'name');
```

Dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Now just run application and call this URL: `http://localhost:8080/api/test`

try to change the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` and see results

if you activate ddl-auto and have a schema.sql, BOTH of them are executed. But normally schema.sql is executed first. So the ddl-auto throws everything away, which was created by schema.sql and data.sql

Comment: Well spotted, but not fixed my issue

Comment: try to remove all h2 properties in application.properties, and tell me what happend

Comment: Same as before, nothing retrieved from DB.

Comment: can you add whole service class, and how you are calling the service method

Comment: Service method is called from Controller, happy all is working correctly into there. Just DB/DAO layer not returning data/not being initialised correctly.

Comment: From logs:
2016-07-11 23:02:31.851  INFO 888 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from URL [file:/C:/Users/ben/workspace/club-management/target/classes/data.sql]

Looks like that is trying to execute as is.



My schema.sql IS lowercase already.

Comment: My schema.sql IS lowercase already. Used create in ddl-auto because I want a fresh DB on each start, should then load data.sql after(see log snippet above)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117028/discussion-between-safwan-hijazi-and-dafoot).

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Just gives you an spring boot opinionated inclusion to the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` maven file, for the bill of material of all the dependencies. To use any one of the dependency defined in the Dependency management of the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` pom you will have to explicitly declare the dependency in dependency section of your pom file.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
  <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

To get the h2 database up and running with your application, you can specifiy the properties in your application.properties file at `src/main/resources/application.properties` use:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2DB
```

so when you run your application with spring application starter, you will be able to access the application at `http://localhost:8080/h2DB` login to the DB and you can verify if the database had the inserts in it or not?

Don't find the data in there then you know where to make a change to keep the data there.

Comment: I tried the console thing earlier, but trying again with the updated config you suggest gives me the same issue. Console is displayed but get a "POST not supported" whenever I submit the form, whether testing or trying to connect.

Comment: You will have to add method=RequestType.POST  on you target method to process the request.by default all requests are considered to be GET requests and the form you are submitting would be POST request

Comment: That would be true if i were referring to one of my controller mappings rather than the h2 console